# How to obtain extrinsic hash

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic

PolkadotJS explorer provides a hash value for every extrinsic (see marked screenshot) but the extrinsics list from block data (`block.extrinsics`) does not explicitly provide one. How is this value obtained?

```
// A snippet of block data object with extrinsics list without hash values
{
    "header": {
        "parentHash": "0xf1b7dd959ccf1fd4d3fbb4899d80a2b2a39532237583e513625c74184b455deb",
        "number": "9,239,202",
        "stateRoot": "0x1c46f814b57b5ce14048f45158ae9e639d23af331542049337d0c137acc17ba8",
        "extrinsicsRoot": "0x828199393cd2f976bf42ed44f026005a5605f07e4d18781ab48a00d67f22b34f",
        "digest": {
            "logs": [
                ...
            ]
        }
    },
    "extrinsics": [
        {
            "isSigned": false,
            "method": {
                "args": {
                    "now": "1,646,142,240,003"
                },
                "method": "set",
                "section": "timestamp"
            }
        },
        {
            "isSigned": false,
            "method": {
                "args": {
                    "data": {
                        "bitfields": [
                            {
                                "payload": "0b00100001_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000",
                                "validatorIndex": "0",
                                "signature": "0xf4cea4e34cf0ad5a15ec171659b2548ae56317eca6aa53d0d2c7a8cb3cb2fd08666673c2991182101c7474452f28b027f8d41ee07e41244987261d988482e986"
                            },
                            ...
                        ],
                      ...
                    }
                },
                "method": "enter",
                "section": "paraInherent"
            }
        },
        {
            "isSigned": true,
            "method": {
                "args": {
                    "dest": {
                        "Id": "1urK7po3hNyt9FWSbUrMspUGkWw69ChF1KDkcs4Do3F3HoV"
                    },
                    "value": "46,620,000,000,000"
                },
                "method": "transferKeepAlive",
                "section": "balances"
            },
            "era": {
                "MortalEra": {
                    "period": "512",
                    "phase": "158"
                }
            },
            "nonce": "81,499",
            "signature": "0x675bc56707feb5dc7a0cc90f40ccb21d8dd29733dea0e200c21b7eebabe952c903f31f0b8d57beaf17f578e1c58203de3981d2db4d9a9f1aaf6501ef6b771106",
            "signer": {
                "Id": "16hp43x8DUZtU8L3cJy9Z8JMwTzuu8ZZRWqDZnpMhp464oEd"
            },
            "tip": "0"
        },
        {
            "isSigned": true,
            "method": {
                "args": {
                    "dest": {
                        "Id": "12xtAYsRUrmbniiWQqJtECiBQrMn8AypQcXhnQAc6RB6XkLW"
                    },
                    "value": "86,098,832,999,986"
                },
                "method": "transfer",
                "section": "balances"
            },
            "era": {
                "MortalEra": {
                    "period": "64",
                    "phase": "30"
                }
            },
            "nonce": "0",
            "signature": "0xaaa69f52ad20cb51aeedd3ad341fdcba34a19ea0f2fbafea643cf182b01b2e115a246df31ac07f940bf2f1bc5584325faaba178759369058273a313b37ce358e",
            "signer": {
                "Id": "13fkvT1NZnWVu762tMCP5Se8wXZPzuawJgW2qJYFTidB7rbq"
            },
            "tip": "0"
        },
        {
            "isSigned": true,
            "method": {
                "args": {
                    "dest": {
                        "Id": "12xtAYsRUrmbniiWQqJtECiBQrMn8AypQcXhnQAc6RB6XkLW"
                    },
                    "value": "57,471,153,886"
                },
                "method": "transfer",
                "section": "balances"
            },
            "era": {
                "MortalEra": {
                    "period": "64",
                    "phase": "30"
                }
            },
            "nonce": "0",
            "signature": "0x1c736068e09d6005a099089f905d1cdc22547109b957c71cbce5cab3dd01b06a7263ec2be84eb1b74742c5e19c907ab3e2deac528d52104d27e0317bb42edc8a",
            "signer": {
                "Id": "14dGnV6asvvAXjE8fffv5d3C3BeGCRUDuidXfK6LDwTPiqAt"
            },
            "tip": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Extrinsic hash on polkadot explorer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With polkadot{.js} API you should be able to get the extrinsic hash:

```
// the hash for each extrinsic in the block
signedBlock.block.extrinsics.forEach((ex, index) => {
  console.log(index, ex.hash.toHex());
});
```

Source: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/blocks#how-do-i-retrieve-the-headerextrinsic-hash-from-blocks